# Get package type difinitions/auto-completion for node_modules package while running wsl2 docker

Tags: docker, nestjs

I'm trying to build a development setup with Docker + WSL2 on windows.
The git repository is cloned inside WSL2 and is open via `code .` so a remote connection between vscode and wsl2. The problem is because the node_modules or packages is installed inside the container and not within the repo itself - my vs code is complaining that the packages im importing is not found.

The question 1:
Is there anyway for my WSL2 vscode to know that i have docker container running and the node_modules or packages is inside the container?

The question 2:
Do i really have to create a link between wsl2 and the running container to resolve this ? or i could just install the dependencies within the repository inside wsl2? But is that best practice?

[image: module not found]

[image: container is running via docker compose]

docker file
[image: the docker file]

docker compose
[image: the docker compose]